# ios UINavigationController subview frame issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, frame, addsubview

here's my code in `mainViewController.m`:

```
#import "SideViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad{
     SideViewController *sideVC = [[SideViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:sideVC.view];          
}
```

`mainViewController` was **embedded in** `UINavigationController` via storyboard

`sideViewController` was **added** to `UINavigationController` as its **subview** because I needed it cover the `Navigation Bar`

and how it shows on iOS8 simulator:
[image]

How could I make it fit the screen bounds?

Comment: Hello , Were u able to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess autoresize mask solve this problem:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
        sideVC = [SideViewController new];
        [sideVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        sideVC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    }

    return self;
}
```